# Change the y axis length for boxplots with R

Tags: r, plot, boxplot, yaxis

is there a way to increase the y axis length to the maximun value?
When I use this code:

```
 par(mfrow=c(3,5))
 for (i in c("mrts","p100e10","p75","PIA","pop1076","pop1616","pop2911","pop500","pop800","rev84","SugarCaneFarms","Swiss","USbanks","UScities","UScolleges"))
 {
   boxplot(dados[[i]],xlab=i)
 }
```

But then it appears boxplots with a low y axis. I need to change the y axis but I didnt want to change one by one, I want to appear the last value.

[Boxplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGJ8F.png)

How Can I do that?
If it is not possible, how can I do it one by one?
Thanks

Comment: Please include all data and code necessary to reproduce your problem. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify *ylim* with the minimal and maximal values of the y axis.
In your example:

```
boxplot(dados[[i]],xlab=i,ylim=c(min(dados[[i]]),max(dados[[i]])))
```

Comment: Thank you for your ansewr. But it still didnt do what I wanted. I wanted a way to change the names in the Y vector, so that it showed the maximun one. Just the format.

Comment: If I get it right you want to change the breakpoints of the y axis so that the highest value be exactly the maximum. 
`boxplot(dados[[i]],xlab=i,yaxt="n"

Comment: ) and
`axis(side=2,at=c(min(dados[i]),max(dados[i])))`
If you want _n_ breakpoints just change c(min,max) to seq(min,max,length.out=_n_)

Answer (score 0):

```
ylim=c(-min,max)
```

It's a corollary of xlim and should solve your issue.